# Can't extract all cookies in Java Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, cookies

In my current application i m developing i need to exctract all cookies from the user browser created by the application server. 
The problem is that with Chrome and Opera i am able to get all cookies and this is fine, but using Firefox and IE only some of them.
When i check if the cookies i need are crated in the browser history i see that they are but can't be got in my java servlet.

What i do is as follow:

```
public static Cookie getCookieByName(String cookieName, HttpServletRequest request) {
        Cookie cookie = null;
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        if (cookies != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                Cookie c = cookies[i];
                if (c.getName().compareTo(cookieName) == 0) {
                    cookie = c;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookie;
    }
```

For Firefox and Opera the returned cookies are JSESSIONID, __utma ... but there are missing cookies .. the ones i need..
Any idea how to proceed ?

Comment: why are you using cookies? Why not to use hidden inputs in the form and pass your variables back and forth between server and browser?

Answer (score 4):

The browser will send the cookies that it thinks are appropriate to send, and you won't be able to convince it to send any more.

What you need to do is to examine the details of the cookies that are not being sent to figure out what distinguishes them from the ones that are being sent.  Things to look at include:

- the cookie's domain
- the cookie's path
- the cookie's port
- the cookie's 'secure' flag

[RFC 2965 - HTTP State Management Mechanism](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2965.html) may be helpful in sorting this out.

Comment: Thanks for this; in my case Chrome could read/use the cookie, but not FF or IE.  Turns out the cookie had an inexact 'path' but started working on all browsers after I set `cookie.setPath(contextPath)` while creating the cookie on the server-side

Answer (score 2):

Use Firebug to check if those cookies are really sent to the server by Firefox, and if their name matches the name you're searching for. Also add some debug traces and print the names of all the cookies.

Maybe you have some path set in the cookie, and Firefox is stricter than IE.